# Orthogonal Projection Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$M=I_n-P,$$  $$ P=X(X'X)^{-1}X' $$ and $$Z=Xu$$ matrices, where $Z$ lies in the column space of $X$.
$$$$If $M$ and $X$ are orthogonal, i.e, $MX=(I_n-P)X=X-PX=X-X=0$ then $MZ=Z-PZ=0$. How prove it? $$$$
My attempt: $MZ=Xu-PXu=Z-u=(X-I_n) u$.

2. If $X$ can be descomposed in $[X_1,X_2]$ then $MX_1=X_1$. How prove it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe for the first question, you can take the following approach:

$$
MZ = \left(I_{n}-P\right)Z=\left(I_{n}-P\right)Xu=\left(X-PX\right)u
$$

We know that $X-PX=0$, so

$$
MZ=\left(X-PX\right)u=0u=0
$$.

I hope this helps.